# Trouble to make a request with httparty

Tags: ruby, rest-client, httparty

I'm using rest-client to make some request in a API, inside my automation scenarios with cucumber.

I'm trying to change the gem to Httparty but I can not do it.

```
url_login = "https://mu.com/login"

header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

payload =
{
    "username": "cpd141",
    "password": "****",
    "agentSign": "ASS"
}.to_json
```

rest-client gem

```
response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: url_login, payload: payload, headers: header)

response - <RestClient::Response 200 "{\"id\":\"1436...">
```

httparty gem

```
response = HTTParty.post(url_login,headers: header, body: payload)

response = {"errorMessage"=>"RequestId: 04377c34-709b-41f3-a379-65615fca2681 Process exited before completing request"}
```

Comment: Try passing `payload` without converting it to `JSON` first

Comment: I just tried and nothing has changed.